# what's the difference between Scriptlet Expression and el

Tags: jsp, el, scriptlet

it was on my exam paper, and i don't know when is the proper timing to use each expression. they can calculate numbers, and put data into variables.
so I couldn't catch certain difference between there..
can someone know that?
let me know that.. I'm confusing :/

"<%=%>"

${}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both serves the same purpose in the end, i.e writing java code in JSP, but there are some caveats

- JSTL i.e expression language `${}` is introduced to separate the View from the Business Logic to adhere with MVC pattern.
- you can reuse the JSTL code by importing libs, same is not the case with scriptlets.
- It's hard to maintain the code that is written in scriptlets and it's not unit testable.

that's the reason

> Where possible, avoid JSP scriptlets whenever tag libraries(JSTL) provide equivalent functionality.